# How to enable/disable ActionMailer upon request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I need to disable/enable ActionMailer upon user request.

For example, if user selects **disable** emails, no email will be sent till he turns it on.

How to do this, **without adding any conditions** to Model callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check this in mail interceptor. Good article [here](http://thepugautomatic.com/2012/08/abort-mail-delivery-with-rails-3-interceptors/)

The inelegant thing here is to get users via their email from the message.

Comment: Great reference, Thanks!